# How to POST JSON Data via HTTP API using VBScript?

Tags: json, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

Trying to Send JSON POST Request to an HTTP API(PushBullet). But facing error in the code. Any help appreciated. [Reference to the document to send push notification](https://docs.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/)

```
Dim objXmlHttpMain , URL

strJSONToSend = {"type": "note", "title": "Alert", "body": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum."}

URL="https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes" 
Set objXmlHttpMain = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
on error resume next 
objXmlHttpMain.open "POST",URL, False 
objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer <api secret id>"
objXmlHttpMain.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"


objXmlHttpMain.send strJSONToSend

set objJSONDoc = nothing 
set objResult = nothing
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Going out on a limb here, since you didn't deem it necessary to include the actual error message. You're most likely getting an "invalid character" error in line 3. That's because you need to define your JSON string as an actual string.

Change this:

```
strJSONToSend = {"type": "note", "title": "Alert", "body": "Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum."}
```

into this:

```
strJSONToSend = "{""type"": ""note"", ""title"": ""Alert"", ""body"": ""Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum.""}"
```

---

**Edit:** As a side-note, if you're using `On Error Resume Next` in your code *always* put proper error handling in place, and also keep it as localized as possible:

```
On Error Resume Next   'enable error handling
objXmlHttpMain.open "POST",URL, False
If Err Then            'handle errors
  WScript.Echo Err.Description & " [0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & "]"
  WScript.Quit 1
End If
On Error Goto 0        'disable error handling again
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! Iam sorry iam very new to vbscript!

Comment: Can this be wrapped in a sub or function and called when / if needed?

Comment: @NCollinsTE Sure.